# create_association_name does not create an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Inside the card model, I have the following code which should create a `meta_sm2` model after the `card` model is created.

```
  after_create :add_meta

  private

  def add_meta
    create_meta_sm2
  end
```

However, when a card model is created the `meta_sm2` model is not created but a select query statement is fired (see screenshot below).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because the `create_meta_sm2` cannot create a valid record.

My solution is to set a `before_validation` hook inside the `meta_sm2` model.